# Im looking for a word that describes someone being intentionally critical after you have forced them to do something

Tags: single-word-requests

Im looking for a word that describes someone who after being put into a situation they didn't want to be apart of they then get extremely critical of the person that asked them to do something.

in some ways they are being passive aggressive at the person. I do not think that fits as a one word answer.

I originally thought of Sarcastic but that does not describe the action correctly. I feel overly critical plays into the question.

Comment: You might try "vengeful, "vindictive," "spiteful."

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say there is no such word for that very specific circumstance.

Comment: I need names.  Let's say A pushed B into doing something.  Now, B feels *resentful*.  B is *taking his frustration out on A*.  B *lashes out at* A.